# How to trigger event when a widget reaches certain position of the screen?

Tags: flutter

I want an event to be triggered when a widget is at a certain position of the screen. Let's say for example that we have a `Container` Widget that is still not visible. It is at a certain position of a scrollable `Scaffold` whose body's height is enough to have to be scrolled. We start to scroll and when the widget is visible and, let's say, reaches the middle of the screen, this triggers the event. In other words, the event should be triggered only if the Widget is at a certain position. Maybe something similar could be achieved with a `ScrollController` but I wonder if there could be other approaches for this.

Comment: Do you mean that you wanna trigger a function when the widget is visible in the list?

Comment: I think I do. Just to be sure, what do you mean with "the list"?

Comment: But not just visible, but also "at a certain position on the screen"

Comment: for certain position not sure but for visibility you can use visibility detector widget

Comment: Great. That's already good info. Checking that out.

Comment: Try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list

Comment: I'd rather not use any package, but I think analyzing it could be of benefit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I started a little research and I found that what I wanted can be achieved with RenderBox objects. By using them you're able to get the size (of type `Size`) or position (of type `Offset`). Once you have them it is very easy to trigger an event. In this case I made a simple example, where I print a statement only if the position of a Container surpasses a given Offset on y axis (say, a specific percentage of the height of the screen, which you can obtain with `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`). I set my limit to a 75% of the screen's height. The event is called when pressing the `FloatingActionButton`. If you'll test it, scroll a little, then press the button. Scroll again, and check it again and so on. You'll see that the event triggers when the limit is surpassed.

I achieved this with help of the following article: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-widget-size-and-position-b0a9ffed9407

Here my example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  GlobalKey _keyRed = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey _keyPurple = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey _keyGreen = GlobalKey();
  Offset positionGreen;

  _getSizes(){
    RenderBox renderBoxRed = _keyRed.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    Size sizeRed = renderBoxRed.size;
    print("red size is: $sizeRed");

    RenderBox renderBoxPurple = _keyRed.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    Size sizePurple = renderBoxPurple.size;
    print("purple size is: $sizePurple");


    RenderBox renderBoxGreen = _keyGreen.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    Size sizeGreen = renderBoxGreen.size;
    print("green size is: $sizeGreen");
  }

  _getPositions(){
    final RenderBox renderBoxRed = _keyRed.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final positionRed = renderBoxRed.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    print("red position is: $positionRed");

    final RenderBox renderBoxPurple = _keyPurple.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final positionPurple = renderBoxPurple.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    print("purple position is: $positionPurple");

    final RenderBox renderBoxGreen = _keyGreen.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    positionGreen = renderBoxGreen.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    print("green position is: $positionGreen");
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double limit = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.75;

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        onPressed: (){
          _getSizes();
          _getPositions();

          print("\npositionGreen in dy is ${positionGreen.dy} and limit is $limit");

          if(positionGreen.dy > limit){
            print("screen resizes");
          } else {
            print("screen doesn't resize");
          }

        },
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 400,
              key: _keyRed,
            color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 600,
              key: _keyPurple,
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 800,
              key: _keyGreen,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```